# Expand one column in a tibble and have the descriptive columns follow

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo, tibble, modelr

I want to use `zoo::na.approx` (but not married to this function) to fill in a response variable for the missing days in my dataframe. I'm having a tough time figuring out how to add the NAs to the original dataframe so that na.approx can fill them in.

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
 df<-data.frame(trt=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                day = c(1,3,7,9,1,5,8,9),
                value = c(7,12,5,7,5,6,11,8),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want every day to be in the dataframe with "NA" for each day where I don't have data.

I have used something like this to expand my dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

days_possible <- expand.grid(
  day = seq(from=min(df$day), max(df$day), by=1),
  trt = c("A", "B"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
   )

new_df<- df %>%
   right_join(days_possible, by = c("trt", "day"))
```

My problem is that I have a bunch of sites, years, and a few treatment columns, so somewhere it seems to all get messed up and in my `days_possible` dataframe, I don't get it right.

Is there a function to avoid this mess, expand one column, and have all the other columns expand in a tidy fashion?  I'm looking at `modelr::data_grid`, but by itself I am not sure how to get the final desired result - an ordered dataframe I can group by treatments and use approximation to fill in missing days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `complete` and `full_seq` functions from the `tidyr` package. The final `as.data.frame()` is not required. I just added it to print the output as a data frame.

```
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  complete(trt, day = full_seq(day, period = 1)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

df2
#    trt day value
# 1    A   1     7
# 2    A   2    NA
# 3    A   3    12
# 4    A   4    NA
# 5    A   5    NA
# 6    A   6    NA
# 7    A   7     5
# 8    A   8    NA
# 9    A   9     7
# 10   B   1     5
# 11   B   2    NA
# 12   B   3    NA
# 13   B   4    NA
# 14   B   5     6
# 15   B   6    NA
# 16   B   7    NA
# 17   B   8    11
# 18   B   9     8
```

Comment: Nice one, `complete()` is always a nice one.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess I agree, and `full_seq` is also handy.

Comment: Looks beautiful, but it doesn' t work on my real data - returns what I started with, no errors. I need to figure out what the problem with my original dataframe is - sure your code is solid.

Comment: @Nazer Just a guess. Perhaps you have some other grouping variables. Try to use `ungroup` if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

We have added a `value2` column to `df` in the Note at the end to show that this works with additional columns.

Note that `df` is not a time series and `na.approx` is intended to operate on time series.  To convert it to one read it into zoo object `wide0` and then merge it with a full set of days.  Now we can apply `na.approx` directly as discussed.

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

wide <- df %>% 
   read.zoo(index = "day", split = "trt") %>%
   merge(zoo(, start(.):end(.) + 0)) %>%
   na.approx
```

giving:

```
> wide
  value.A value2.A   value.B value2.B
1    7.00     1.00  5.000000 5.000000
2    9.50     1.50  5.250000 5.250000
3   12.00     2.00  5.500000 5.500000
4   10.25     2.25  5.750000 5.750000
5    8.50     2.50  6.000000 6.000000
6    6.75     2.75  7.666667 6.333333
7    5.00     3.00  9.333333 6.666667
8    6.00       NA 11.000000 7.000000
9    7.00       NA  8.000000 8.000000
```

The NAs above are due to the fact that one cannot interpolate without values on both sides; however, `na.approx` does have additional arguments to fill those in if you want to.

The wide form with separate columns for each variable/group shown above may be the most convenient but if not we could convert it back to long form using `fortify.zoo` and possibly spread out the variables into one column each again.

```
library(tidyr)

wide %>%
     fortify.zoo(wide, melt = TRUE, sep = ".", 
         names = list("day", c("variable", "group"), "value")) %>%
     spread(variable, value)
```

giving:

```
   day group     value   value2
1    1     A  7.000000 1.000000
2    1     B  5.000000 5.000000
3    2     A  9.500000 1.500000
4    2     B  5.250000 5.250000
5    3     A 12.000000 2.000000
6    3     B  5.500000 5.500000
7    4     A 10.250000 2.250000
8    4     B  5.750000 5.750000
9    5     A  8.500000 2.500000
10   5     B  6.000000 6.000000
11   6     A  6.750000 2.750000
12   6     B  7.666667 6.333333
13   7     A  5.000000 3.000000
14   7     B  9.333333 6.666667
15   8     A  6.000000       NA
16   8     B 11.000000 7.000000
17   9     A  7.000000       NA
18   9     B  8.000000 8.000000
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form.  We have added a `value2` column to show it still works.

```
df<-data.frame(trt=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                day = c(1,3,7,9,1,5,8,9),
                value = c(7,12,5,7,5,6,11,8),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$value2 <- c(1:3, NA, 5:8)
```